# getting all the records from table -Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

i have around 13000 records on one table(HashTag -classname) . i want to retrieve all of them on a single query. but parse allows only 1000 per query.  any other ways get the all the records..

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("HashTag");
 query.whereExists("Tag"); query.orderByAscending("Type"); query.setLimit(1000);
 query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

                                @Override
                                public void done(List<ParseObject> list,
                                        ParseException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    if (e == null)
                                    {
                                        if (list.size() > 0) {
                                            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                                                ParseObject p = list.get(i);
                                                String tagid = p.getString("Tag");
                                                String Type = p.getString("Type");
                                                class2 c2 = new class2();
                                                c2.type = "" + Type;
                                                c2.tag = "" + tagid;
                                                listClass2.add(c2);



                                            }

                                        }
```

Comment: in the parse data browser see "MORE" dropdown then "Export Class"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Declare  a global variable for storing the complete data
private static List<ParseObject>allObjects;
allObjects=new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
ParseQuery<ParseObject>query3=ParseQuery.getQuery("HashTag");
query3.whereExists("Tag");
query3.setLimit(1000);
query3.findInBackground(getallobjects());
int limit=1000;
int skip=0;
//callback method:
private FindCallback<ParseObject>getallobjects(){  
    return new FindCallback<ParseObject>(){
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject>list,ParseException e){
            allObjects.addAll(list);
            if(list.size()==limit){
                skip=skip+limit;
                ParseQuery<ParseObject>query=ParseQuery.getQuery("HashTag");
                query.setSkip(skip);
                query.setLimit(limit);
                query.findInBackground(getallobjects());
            }else{
                //you have full data in allobjects
                for(int i=0;i<allObjects.size();i++){}
            }
        }}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can run multiple queries on the same table, with query's `skip` property incremented by 1000 each time:

1. Get the total number of records via `query.count()`, and use it to set a 'skip' variable
2. Run a new query for each 1000 records, updating your skip property accordingly
3. Process records as normal when each query returns

Something like this:

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("HashTag");
    query.whereExists("Tag");
    query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
        public void done(int count, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
              // The count request succeeded. Run the query multiple times using the query count
          int numQueries = Math.ceil(count / 1000); //Gives you how many queries to run
          for(int skipNum = 0; l < numQueries; l++){
             ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("HashTag");
             query.whereExists("Tag"); query.orderByAscending("Type"); 
             query.setLimit(skipNum * 1000);
             query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                //Run your query as normal here

             }
          }
        } else {
          // The request failed
        }
      }
```

Comment: will this increase api query call??

Comment: Yes, you have to make an API call for each query, so 13000 records = 13 queries. (BTW, this is also the accepted solution suggested by Parse themselves - see here: https://www.parse.com/questions/how-can-i-get-thousands-of-records-at-a-time)

Answer (score 0):

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("TestObject");
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                    for(ParseObject p : list){

                        Log.d("--", (String) p.get("foo")+p.getCreatedAt());
                    }
                }
            });
```